# Blazor C# AuthenticationStateTask User.Identity Remains even when Logging Out

Tags: authentication, signalr, blazor

Right, so I can't find any questions similar to my issue or any possible fixes for my issue.

Basically, I have a Blazor App (Server-Side) which makes use of Individual Account Authentication with use of Roles.

A section of the App, is a listing of currently Logged-In users (Using Signal R, to check for Users currently Logged-In by using a simple List of Users and their last "pinged" datetime.)

A ping happens every 10 seconds to query all connected users, and return their user.Identity.Name along with the DateTime at the moment of ping. Then the DateTime is compared in the list and if any of the Users last pinged time vs latest pinged time is greater than 15 seconds, we assume they are no longer logged in, or have the Tab open and remove them from the list. This all works well enough since we ping every 10 seconds, and have a 15 sec window before marking as logged out/offline.

The problem however, is the AuthenticationStateTask seemingly retains a users Identity even when Logging out?

Eg. I log in as User1 > pings happen as expected. I log-out. Pings still happen... it still hits the AuthenticationStateTask and still picks up a User identity somehow (And still shows as Authenticated). I then log in as User2, and start getting returns for both User1 and User2.

As extension to this problem, even closing the browser window after logging out doesn't actually stop pings from happening... only when completely closing the browser will the pings stop.

If anyone has any clue as to why this is happening, please let me know. Even if I'm being silly, and the problem is obvious tell me where I messed up. If more information is needed let me know, and I'll update.

Much thanks!

Comment: Do you have any GitHub repo?